# SceneKit Button show delay

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, scenekit

I'm trying to create a 3D game with Swift. When the player dies, a UIButton should show on the screen. The problem is that the button has a very big delay (something like 5 seconds) till the button shows. I've used the same code as I would use for a SpriteKit game. I tried to print a message in the console when the button should show and this message came without delay.

My Button:

```
func createRespawnButton() {
    restartButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 50))
    restartButton.setTitle("Play Again!", for: UIControlState.normal)
    restartButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.cyan, for: UIControlState.normal)
    restartButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
    restartButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.restartGame), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)

    self.view.addSubview(restartButton)
}
```

This function is called when 2 cars collide with each other. Can someone help me to make my button show on the screen without such a big delay?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit):

> For the most part, use UIKit classes only from your app’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your app’s user interface in any way.

Is your function called in the main thread? `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` delegation methods are called in SceneKit's rendering queue. If that's where you detect collisions, you will want to dispatch your function call to the main queue:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   createRespawnButton()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! It worked perfectly! Thanks mate!